# Phonegap inAppBrowser events are only firing once

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, dom-events, inappbrowser

I am using phonegap 2.9 (via PhoneGap Build) on Android 4.1. I am loading up another site in the InAppBrowser, which is all very well.

```
 ref = window.open('http://someOtherPage.com', '_blank', 'location=yes,hidden=no');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
        ref.insertCSS({code:'.header { display:none; }'}, function(){
            ref.show();
         });         

    });
```

This works fine, and as you can see in the code above, I insert some CSS after the page has loaded.

I have an issue however, if I navigate to another page within the inAppBrowser, namely, the events don't fire again, not loadstop, loadstart, etc. These events will only fire once. This seems to be contrary to spec which states:

> "loadstart: event fires when the InAppBrowser starts to load a URL."

I would really like to be able to modify every page on the site I am opening, not just the first one.

Answer (score -1):

You can just remove ref.show() and will work

```
 ref = window.open('http://someOtherPage.com', '_blank', 'location=yes,hidden=no');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
        ref.insertCSS({code:'.header { display:none; }'});         

    });
```